# Why am I getting a mismatch error in this vba script?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

On the line "EmailItem.To = Str(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2))" when i try to run it it comes up as a mismatch error how would i fix this?

Here is the code

```
Sub SendEmail_Example1()

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

EmailItem.To = Str(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2))
EmailItem.CC = "marcusburr@gmail.com"
EmailItem.Subject = "Test Email From Excel VBA"
EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is my first email from Excel" & _
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Regards," & vbNewLine & _
"VBA Coder"


EmailItem.Send

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EmailItem.To = Str(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2))
```

`Str` expects a numeric argument.  Are you thinking of `CStr()` ?